# How do I turn off thumbnails for pdf files?

Tags: lubuntu, pdf, thumbnails

When I open `org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers` using `dconf-editor`, I see this:

```
Schema:     `org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers`
Summary:     List of mime-types for which external thumbnailer programs will be disabled
Description: Thumbnails will not be created for files whose mime-type is contained in the list.
Type:        as
Default:     []
```

When I enter `[application/pdf]` as shown in the image I get an error. Entering just `application/pdf` also gives me a similar error.

[image: dconf-editor error]

My questions are:

- What is meant by "external thumbnailer program"? I have not installed any such thing.
- Is `org.gnome.desktop.thumbnailers` the appropriate schema to use to turn off thumbnails for pdf files generated presumably by default? If not, is there any way to stop pdf file thumbnails from being generated?

I'm using Thunar as file manager and xfdesktop instead of PCManFM on Lubuntu 13.04..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. A thumbnailer is a program with no user interface that takes a file and a pixel size as inputs, and it writes a thumbnail for that file. GNOME determines which thumbnailer program to use based on the MIME type of the file for which a thumbnail is to be generated. The mapping between MIME types and thumbnailer programs is stored as a series of GConf keys.
   <sub>[Source](https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/thumbnailer.html.en)</sub>
2. Yes it's the correct way to disable thumbnails for any mime-type. The reason it's not working for you is incorrect syntax. You need to use single quotes around `application/pdf`. So it should be like this:

   ```
   ['application/pdf']
   ```

   You can use a comma without space to separate multiple mime-types:

   ```
   ['application/pdf','image/jpeg']
   ```